# Analogue to superior highly composite numbers for the unitary divisor function

Tags: prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

For which positive integers $n$ does there exist a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that

$\dfrac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^\epsilon}\geq\dfrac{2^{\omega(k)}}{k^\epsilon}$ for all $k<n$, and

$\dfrac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^\epsilon}>\dfrac{2^{\omega(k)}}{k^\epsilon}$ for all $k>n$?

A divisor $d$ of $n$ is called *unitary* if $\gcd(d,n/d)=1$, therefore the unitary divisors are precisely the numbers resulting from expanding the product $(p_1^{a_1}+1)\cdots(p_{\omega(n)}^{a_{\omega(n)}}+1)$, where $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_{\omega(n)}^{a_{\omega(n)}}$ is the canonical prime factorization of $n$. It follows that $n$ has $2^{\omega(n)}$ unitary divisors, compared to $d(n)=(a_1+1)\cdots(a_{\omega(n)}+1)$ divisors unitary or not.

This is of the same form as the definition of a superior highly composite number:

$n$ is called *superior highly composite* if

$\dfrac{d(n)}{n^\epsilon}\geq\dfrac{d(k)}{k^\epsilon}$ for all $k<n$, and

$\dfrac{d(n)}{n^\epsilon}>\dfrac{d(k)}{k^\epsilon}$ for all $k>n$

Which values satisfy this (the first) definition? I don't know of a method for finding them.

Edit: Every superior highly composite number is a *highly composite number*, $n$ such that $d(n)>d(k)$ for all $k<n$. Likely the numbers satisfying the unitary analogue of superior highly composite numbers are a subset of the numbers $n$ such that $\omega(k)<\omega(n)$ for all $k<n$, which are the *primorials*, products of the first $n$ primes.

Comment: finished proof, put in sketch, easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was hasty before. I can probably write out a proof tomorrow afternoon, but it is already clear that numbers produced by your recipe are all the primorials and nothing else. I made an unimportant switch to
$$ \frac{e^{\omega(n)}}{n^\epsilon} $$

For $\epsilon = 2.0,$ the winner is $n=1.$

For $\epsilon = 1.0,$ the winner is $n=2.$

For $\epsilon = 0.7,$ the winner is $n=6.$

For $\epsilon = 0.6,$ the winner is $n=30.$

For $\epsilon = 0.5,$ the winner is $n=210.$

For $\epsilon = 0.4,$ the winner is $n=2310.$

For $\epsilon = 0.38,$ the winner is $n=30030.$

For $\epsilon = 0.35,$ the winner is $n=510510.$

Note that I actually calculated $\omega(n) - \epsilon \log n.$ You see how it does not matter about $e$ against $2,$ I could calculate $ A \omega(n) - \epsilon \log n$ and simply replace it by $  \omega(n) - (\epsilon / A) \log n$

EDIT: proof  easier than usual. It is the primorial with all prime factors satisfying $$  p \leq e^{1 / \epsilon}. $$

At the same time, the first (largest) $\epsilon$ that includes a given prime $p$ is $$  \epsilon = \frac{1}{\log p}.   $$
which is irrational.